# onSubmit firing twice in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

So my `main.ts` file looks like this:

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './components/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

The problem is with `onSubmit` method in my component, it fires twice. I've read this thead:
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9954 but the solution is outdated.
Then I've found this: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9813
But this also didn't work for me. Do you know any other fixes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn out it was my bad, I was calling the onSubmit method twice in html, through form and button.

Answer (score 0):

The first request can be OPTIONS type and the second request is whatever the method you have specified. Did you check the inspector tools?

Comment: I didn't quite understand what you meant. Could you please specify what should I checl?